# Flutter Custom marker with TextWidget

Tags: flutter, google-maps-markers

I want to use a custom marker(`.png` image which is inside the assets folder) in the map, and over the marker, I want to show numbers like in the picture. I saw several questions but they were using a custom marker only. Not with a text widget. How can I do that?    I tried this code but I getting an error

> Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path =
> 'assets/images/mappin.png' (OS Error: No such file  or directory,
> errno = 2)

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  List<Map> list = [];
  final LatLng _center = const LatLng(6.521563, 79.677433);
  final Set<Marker> _markers = {};
  final Set<String> unshopid = {};

  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};

  @override
  void initState() {
    retrivedata();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  retrivedata() async {
    DatabaseReference dboffer =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Offers");
    await dboffer.onValue.listen((event) {
      var snapshot = event.snapshot;

      Map<dynamic, dynamic> up = snapshot.value;

      setState(() {
        up.forEach((key, value) {
          list.add(value);
          // unshpoid.add(value['shopid']);
          // createbitmap(value,"3");
          print(value['shoplat']);
          print(value['shoplng']);
          unshopid.add(value['shopid']);
          // createpins();
        });

        print(list.length);

        unshopid.forEach((e1) {
          String shopidis = e1;
          int offercount = 0;

          print(' shop id unique' + shopidis);

          list.forEach((e2) async {
            if (shopidis == e2['shopid']) {
              print('matchesd --  ' + shopidis);
              offercount++;

              final Marker marker = Marker(
                
                  icon: await getMarkerIcon("assets/images/mappin.png",
                      Size(150.0, 150.0), offercount.toString())
                      );

              _markers.add(marker);
            }


          });
        });
      });
      return "";
    });
  }

  void _getpinlocation() {
    getCurrentProjection(mapController);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      children: [
        GoogleMap(
          markers: _markers,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
          onCameraIdle: _getpinlocation,
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: _center,
            zoom: 4.0,
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 0.0,
          top: 0.0,
          right: 0.0,
          child: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(56.0),
              child: AppBar(
                title: Center(
                  child: Text("Foodom"),
                ),
                elevation: 2.0,
              )),
        ),
        DraggableSearchableListView(),
      ],
    ));
  }

  void getCurrentProjection(GoogleMapController mapController) async {
    final LatLngBounds screenBounds = await mapController.getVisibleRegion();
    print(screenBounds.northeast.latitude);
  }

  Future<BitmapDescriptor> getMarkerIcon(
      String imagePath, Size size, String titletext) async {
    final ui.PictureRecorder pictureRecorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    final Canvas canvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);

    final Radius radius = Radius.circular(size.width / 2);

    final Paint tagPaint = Paint()..color = Colors.blue;
    final double tagWidth = 40.0;

    final Paint shadowPaint = Paint()..color = Colors.blue.withAlpha(100);
    final double shadowWidth = 15.0;

    final Paint borderPaint = Paint()..color = Colors.white;
    final double borderWidth = 3.0;

    final double imageOffset = shadowWidth + borderWidth;

    // Add shadow circle
    canvas.drawRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
          Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height),
          topLeft: radius,
          topRight: radius,
          bottomLeft: radius,
          bottomRight: radius,
        ),
        shadowPaint);

    // Add border circle
    canvas.drawRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
          Rect.fromLTWH(shadowWidth, shadowWidth,
              size.width - (shadowWidth * 2), size.height - (shadowWidth * 2)),
          topLeft: radius,
          topRight: radius,
          bottomLeft: radius,
          bottomRight: radius,
        ),
        borderPaint);

    // Add tag circle
    canvas.drawRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
          Rect.fromLTWH(size.width - tagWidth, 0.0, tagWidth, tagWidth),
          topLeft: radius,
          topRight: radius,
          bottomLeft: radius,
          bottomRight: radius,
        ),
        tagPaint);

    // Add tag text
    TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
    textPainter.text = TextSpan(
      text: titletext,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
    );

    textPainter.layout();
    textPainter.paint(
        canvas,
        Offset(size.width - tagWidth / 2 - textPainter.width / 2,
            tagWidth / 2 - textPainter.height / 2));

    // Oval for the image
    Rect oval = Rect.fromLTWH(imageOffset, imageOffset,
        size.width - (imageOffset * 2), size.height - (imageOffset * 2));

    // Add path for oval image
    canvas.clipPath(Path()..addOval(oval));

    // Add image
    ui.Image image = await getImageFromPath(
        imagePath); // Alternatively use your own method to get the image
    paintImage(canvas: canvas, image: image, rect: oval, fit: BoxFit.fitWidth);

    // Convert canvas to image
    final ui.Image markerAsImage = await pictureRecorder
        .endRecording()
        .toImage(size.width.toInt(), size.height.toInt());

    // Convert image to bytes
    final ByteData byteData =
        await markerAsImage.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    final Uint8List uint8List = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

    return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(uint8List);
  }


  Future<ui.Image> getImageFromPath(String imagePath) async {
    File imageFile = File(imagePath);

    Uint8List imageBytes = imageFile.readAsBytesSync();

    final Completer<ui.Image> completer = new Completer();

    ui.decodeImageFromList(imageBytes, (ui.Image img) {
      return completer.complete(img);
    });

    return completer.future;
}
```

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Can you share what you have tried already?

Comment: I'm retrieving the value fro the firebase, after that, i want to show it to the map